# How to scroll into view after rendering a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to scroll my view to a specific component. I'm using refs to keep track of the components and I'm trying to call the scrollIntoView function to move to the specific ref. The problem I'm running into is that nothing happens when I try and put the call to scrollIntoView inside of a useEffect. The command works on mouse click, most likely because the component is already rendered to the screen.

Here's the code I have:

```
import React, { forwardRef, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { Box, Button, Grid, Stack} from '@mui/material';

const component_1 = 'Component 1';
const component_2 = 'Component 2';

export const RefLabel = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const { label } = props;
    return <div ref={ref}>{label}</div>;
});

export const TheComponent = (props) => {

    const sectionRefs = {
        [component_1]: useRef(),
        [component_2]: useRef()
    }
    const navToSection = (section) => {
        sectionRefs[section].current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        //This does not work. The useEffect is called but the scrolling does not happen  
        navToSection(component_9);
    }, []);
    return (
        <Grid container>
            <Stack>
                <Box>
                    <Button onClick={()=>{navToSection(component_2)}>Go to 2</Button>
                    <RefLabel ref=sectionRefs[component_1] label='label 1'>
                    <RefLabel ref=sectionRefs[component_2] label='label 2'>
                </Box>
            </Stack>
        </Grid>
```

In this code the useEffect does not scroll at all. However when pressing the button up top, the scroll view correctly scrolls to the correct RefLabel.

It should also be note that this code creates a scroll panel inside of the browser's scroll bar. Regardless, the scrollIntoView works when called from events after the component has completely rendered. What I need is a way to automatically scroll to a component once after the rendering. Documentation online suggests placing the scroll logic in a useEffect but that is not working for me. (For example: https://www.codemzy.com/blog/react-scroll-to-element-on-render)

Also note that this code is abstracted out from real code, which is why it does weird things like creating 10 components. The real code has an internal scroll bar and the RefLabels are contained within the scroll pane. All of the RefLabels are not visible until they are scrolled to a position where they can be displayed.

Comment: Also check the "Deep dive" box under the react documentation section on scrolling to elements. They show a pretty similar example to what you're trying to achieve: https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#example-scrolling-to-an-element

Comment: Remove some of this code so that it's a reasonable [mcve]: you don't need 10 components to show this off, just a single one will work fine.

Comment: I'll make the change. The reason I had 10 was I wanted an example that was similar to my production code. There are many components inside of the real version and I felt that if I only had one or two then it wouldn't convey that the scroll would work.

Comment: If I put the scroll logic in the useEffect in a setTimeout, then the scrolling works

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running CodeSandbox, fixed some minor syntax issues, and tested the button and the UI scrolled to the specified `RefLabel` component... it worked just fine.

Comment: Maybe the code I pasted is too simple and doesn't capture what I'm seeing in my code. Regardless I was able to get my code to work by putting the scroll logic inside of a timeout. I may delete this question.